# error in nodejs query : Column count doesn't match value count

Tags: mysql, node.js

i have a simple error in nodejs after excuting query:
query is this:

```
INSERT INTO equi_transact (equiId,pid,officeid,pid_p,officeid_p,amvalcode,user) 
VALUES ((SELECT MAX(id) FROM equipmenttbl)+1,3,2,null,null,'165488','admin')
```

my query insert a new query but i recive this error after it :

Error:

> ER_WRONG_VALUE_COUNT_ON_ROW: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

i excute it in mysql directly but not have any error

Comment: please show th code that produces the error as it it not mysql related

Answer (score 0):

```sql
INSERT INTO equi_transact (equiId, pid, officeid, pid_p, officeid_p, amvalcode, user) 
  SELECT 
    (MAX(id) + 1) as 'equiId',
    3 as 'pid',
    2 as 'officeid',
    NULL as 'pid_p',
    NULL as 'officeid_p',
    '165488' as 'amvalcode',
    'admin' as 'user'
  FROM equipmenttbl;
```